# how to center the response and predictor( center at mean) variable using the summary table?

Tags: r, statistics, regression

```
**we dont have the data only summary table is given**        


Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept) -36.8522    12.6560  -2.912 0.005573 ** 
    X1           -0.7120     1.4540  -0.490 0.626747    
   
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    
    Residual standard error: 12.27 on 45 degrees of freedom
    Multiple R-squared:  0.7377,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7144 
    F-statistic: 31.63 on 4 and 45 DF,  p-value: 1.478e-12
```

I know that for centering I need to center predictor that is centered at the mean has new values–the entire scale has shifted so that the mean now has a value of 0.And I know The intercept will change, but the regression coefficient for that variable will not.

Comment: Center your variables and then run the regression again.

Comment: Use the function `scale` before running the model so that the predictor values and the estimates will be in units of std deviations to the mean

Comment: @user2974951 we are not given the data we only have the summary table

Comment: @danlooo  we are not given the data we only have the summary table

Comment: Then you are figuratively screwed.

Comment: Do you have means and variances of the original data? Then, you can normalize the estimates...

Comment: @danloo no the only thing given is the summary table. If I had the data ot mean and var would make it easy to solve but I only have the table.

Comment: Then your task is indeed impossible. Never do statistics if you do not have access to the raw data.

Comment: @danlooo can we somehow find the mean and variance from the summary?

Comment: What is your summary table? An object of class `summary.lm` ? A data.frame?

Comment: @danlooo it's summary of a model. summary(mod1)

Comment: I found `summary(mod1)$cov.unscaled` but nothing about original means

Comment: Then maybe you have everything you need? The relationship between standardized slopes and unstandardized slopes is: beta = b*(sx/sy). Since you have the variance/covariance matrix of the predictors, you have the sx's covered and you can get the sy from the sse/r squared.

Comment: @dfife It's a bit hard for me to understand could you please plug in the variables I am so lost!

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @Someoneii Know -- You could get summary(mod1)$cov.unscaled. Can you also get mod1@model? If so, you have the raw data.

Comment: Sorry, that should have said mod1$model

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have access to the model in R (since you mention you can get the variance/covariance matrix of the betas). If that's the case, then you can convert it using the model.

The relationship between standardized slopes and unstandardized slopes is:

```
beta = b*(sx/sy)
```

Embedded within all `lm`'s is the data, which can be accessed using the following R code:

```
model$model
```

(Assuming the fitted object is called "model")

To get the standardized slopes, all you'd have to do is something like this:

```
get_betas = function(object){
    b = summary(object)$coef[, 1]
    sx = apply(model.matrix(object), 2, sd)
    sy = apply(object$model[1], 2, sd)
    beta <- b * sx/sy
    return(beta)

}
```

Then you would use that function to extract the betas

```
get_betas(model)
```

Comment: I've tried this on an example and the results don't check out.

Comment: I misunderstood what cov.unscaled was. I thought it was the variance/covariance matrix of the predictors....but it's actually x'x(-1). Maybe there's a way to get to X from that? Let me think about that.